# this code run in c++ on gfg but give error of index -1 out of bounds for length 5 in java. Why?

Tags: java

```
int findKRotation(int arr[], int n) {
    // code here
    if(n==1)
    return 0;
    
    int s = 0;
    int e = n - 1;
    while(s<=e){
        int mid = s +(e-s)/2;
        if(arr[mid] >= arr[mid-1] && arr[mid] >= arr[mid+1]){
            return mid+1;
        }
        else if(arr[mid] < arr[n-1]){
            e = mid -1;
        }
        else{
            s = mid +1;
        }
    }
   return s ; 
}
```

this code run in c++ on  gfg but give error of index -1 out of bounds for length 5 in java. Why ?

Comment: Can you add the parameters that make it fail, so it is reproducible? My guess would be that mid at some point is `n-1` in `arr[mid+1]` and that's why java fails. In `C++` you don't have that problem if the array is greater, it depends on how you built it.

Answer (score 1):

The error message "index -1 out of bounds for length 5" means that you are trying to access an element of the array with an index of -1, which is not valid since array indices in Java must be non-negative. I am pretty sure the error occurs if the "mid" variable in the if statement is equal to 0. Then  you try to access it with "arr[mid-1]" witch can't be done since arrays indexes can not be negative.

```
    int findKRotation(int arr[], int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    int s = 0;
    int e = n - 1;

    while (s <= e) {
        int mid = s + (e - s) / 2;

        if (mid == 0 || (arr[mid] >= arr[mid-1] && arr[mid] >= arr[mid+1])) {
            return mid;
        } else if (arr[mid] < arr[n-1]) {
            e = mid - 1;
        } else {
            s = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```